# Web installer for Symfony-project

Tags: symfony, installation

I'm an developer of the [Webworks CRM Open Source](http://www.webworks-crm.org) project.

Now I'm looking for a solution to make the installation simple for non-developers. At this time, the user have to install the project like any other symfony project (via console, composer, etc). Is there anyone who knows about an web installation script for Symfony project?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best choice for you will be [SyliusInstallerBundle](https://github.com/Sylius/SyliusInstallerBundle).

It has installer for CLI and has Web-based installer.

You just need to customise it for your needs, i.e. it doesn't have `composer install` command included. But you can simply add it.

Comment: Sounds good. But the problem is: After downloading the sources, I don't have the vendor packages, so it should be a solution that doesn't bases on the vendor system/composer... The solution must download the vendor packages at first. Maybe possible with a script that runs the console command (php composer.phar update)?

Comment: You just need to add this command. Not the `composer update` but `composer install`. Because you need to be sure that version of all libraries (and your application) is under your control. Execution of `composer install` must be outside of the bundle and be independent of any other libraries. Just pure PHP. After this `composer install` you can launch WebInstaler from Bundle.